# Sent Data View vs Bounce Data View

Tags: marketing-cloud, data-views

I know this is silly question and I believe that the answer is no, but I want to confirm. Can a subscriber be in both the _Sent Data View and the _Bounce Data View?

I figure if an attempt is made, the email is consider sent until a bounce is registered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they can be in both. In fact, there should never be people in your Bounce DV that are not also in your Sent DV (outside retention based discrepancies).

Once a subscriber successfully exits the send queue, then they are added to the Sent DV.  It is after this that then a Bounce would be returned from the receiving ISP (if applicable) and the information would be added to the Bounce DV.

Comment: Thank you for confirming my doubts. And that makes sense to be in both DV's.

Comment: You could check the notsent object via API or WSProxy to gather those that failed send queue if that is what you need. But no way to get that info directly through DV

Comment: Oh... I thought we could use the subscriber DV to determine the sent status. But the api sounds fine to me.